# webcal:// links no longer open Apple Calendar on MacOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, calendar, icalendar, caldav

Our platform publishes our users' calendars as an .ics feed to which they can subscribe to - the feed is generated at runtime using PHP and the links are published using the format of `webcal://domain.com/calendar/very-long-impossible-to-guess-filename.ics` and up until recently, on a Macbook, this would open Apple Calendar -> New Calendar Subscription with a prefilled `Calendar URL`, like this:

[image: Apple iCalendar screenshot]

This is no longer the case - now it opens Google Calendar (inside the browser) which tries to add the calendar to itself - this is not what we want.

Behavior confirmed on Chrome 78 for MacOS Mojave and MacOS Catalina.
It still adds the calendar correctly on iOS.
When clicked on Safari for MacOS, it asks to switch to Chrome, which then, again, proceeds to redirect to Google Calendar.

How do we get back the behavior we had, which is opening Apple Calendar on MacOS through a link? Keep in mind downloaded .ics files aren't an option for us because of our goal which is to let our users keep track of their ever-changing schedules on the site through Apple Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to tell Safari not to open webcal links with Google Calendar by going into the Mac Calendar app. From there, go into Preferences and change the Default Calendar app from Google Chrome back to Calendar. It's frustrating, I certainly never changed that value in the first place!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm experiencing the OP's problem and this Calendar.app preference is _already_ set to "Calendar". Running macOS 13.2.1.